# How do I loop through result objects in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am having problems manually looping through xml data that is received via an HTTPService call, the xml looks something like this:

```
<DataTable>
    <Row>
        <text>foo</text>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <text>bar</text>
    </Row>
</DataTable>
```

When the webservice result event is fired I do something like this:

```
for(var i:int=0;i&lt;event.result.DataTable.Row.length;i++)
{
    if(event.result.DataTable.Row[i].text == "foo")
        mx.controls.Alert.show('foo found!');
}
```

This code works then there is more than 1 "Row" nodes returned. However, it seems that if there is only one "Row" node then the *event.DataTable.Row* object is not an error and the code subsequently breaks.

What is the proper way to loop through the *HTTPService* result object? Do I need to convert it to some type of *XMLList* collection or an *ArrayCollection*? I have tried setting the resultFormat to *e4x* and that has yet to fix the problem...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in this statement

```
event.result.DataTable.Row.length
```

`length` is not a property of `XMLList`, but a method:

```
event.result.DataTable.Row.length()
```

it's confusing, but that's the way it is.

*Addition:* actually, the safest thing to do is to always use a `for each` loop when iterating over `XMLList`s, that way you never make the mistake, it's less code, and easier to read:

```
for each ( var node : XML in event.result.DataTable.Row )
```

Answer (score 2):

Row isn't an array unless there are multiple Row elements. It is annoying. You have to do something like this, but I haven't written AS3 in a while so I forget if there's an exists function.

```
if (exists(event.result.DataTable) && exists(event.result.DataTable.Row)){
  if (exists(event.result.DataTable.Row.length)) {
    for(var i:int=0;i<event.result.DataTable.Row.length;i++)
    {
        if (exists(event.result.DataTable.Row[i].text)
        && "foo" == event.result.DataTable.Row[i].text)
            mx.controls.Alert.show('foo found!');
    }
  }
  if (exists(event.result.DataTable.Row.text)
  && "foo" == event.result.DataTable.Row.text)
      mx.controls.Alert.show('foo found!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store it in an Xml object and then use its methods to search for the node value you need.

```
var returnedXml:Xml = new Xml(event.result.toString());
```